# How can I create custom ID in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

As Far I know, we can create a custom ID using UUIDField().

`id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)`

But how can I change the ID that would look like  `AAYYMMDDNNNN`

Where,

⦁ First 2 characters - 'AA'

⦁ YY - Capture year on which its registered

⦁ MM - Capture month  on which its registered

⦁ DD - Capture current date on which its registered

⦁ NNNN - Random number based on the every day new set of NNNN will be generated (0001 - 9999)

Comment: use id = models.CharField(max_length=12, primary_key=True, default=```generate_id```) where ```generate_id``` is your custom function which returns expected ID

Comment: Can you please let me know how can I create that custom function that would returns me the expected output ?

Comment: @ruddra provided correct answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
import random
from django.utils import timezone

def generate_pk():
    number = random.randint(1000, 9999)
    return 'AA{}{}'.format(timezone.now().strftime('%y%m%d'), number)

class YourModel(models.Model):
   id = models.CharField(default=generate_pk, primary_key=True, max_length=255, unique=True)
```

### Update

Update based on comments, as you want to track if there is any instance created today and increase counter of *NNNN*, you can't use a function to generate default value. Instead try overriding the save method like this:

```
import random
from django.utils import timezone

class YourModel(models.Model):
   special_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)

   def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
       if not self.special_id:
           prefix = 'AA{}'.format(timezone.now().strftime('%y%m%d')
           prev_instances = self.__class__.objects.filter(special_id__contains=prefix))
           if prev_instances.exists():
              last_instance_id = prev_instances.last().special_id[-4:]
              self.special_id = prefix+'{0:04d}'.format(int(last_instance_id)+1)
           else:
               self.special_id = prefix+'{0:04d}'.format(1)
       super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, extremely sorry for not being specific, actually I want the number that would starts from 0001-0002-0003 and so on till 9997 - 9998 - 9999. Also I don't think it will generate  new set of NNNN on the every day???

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by new set of NNNN? also, does this field need to be a primary key?

Comment: For example, Id will generate for today would be AA2006260001 - AA2006260002 - AA2006260003 and soo on till AA2006269999.. and for tomorrow, Id would generate like AA2006270001-AA2006270002 - AA2006270003 till AA2006279999 and for day after tomorrow, Id would generate like AA2006280001-AA2006280002 - AA2006280003 till AA2006289999 and so on

Comment: Then you can't use a method to generate default value. You need to override the save function for this implementation. Please see the updated answer

Comment: Thank You soo much. While implementing this code, I'm facing ValueError : cannot switch from manual field specification to automatic field numbering on this line self.special_id = '{}{0:04d}'.format(prefix, int(last_instance_id)+1) .And for 'd', it's giving another error that is , Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'. Can you please explain me this line. ? and

Comment: @sodmzs If I may interject, please use that code as a starting point. It is rather rude to expect others to write all your code for you.

Comment: Thank You Sooooo MUCCCCCHHHH!!!! You Are Awesome Human!!!!!!!!!! <3